# enum or typedef enum for return values

Tags: c, enums, constants, typedef

I have a function that tests for several different states of the system.

I could either use

```
enum
{
   limit   = -2,
   timeout = -1,
   ongoing =  0,
   finished=  1
};
```

The function would then be defined as:

```
static int test(void);
```

I personally prefer the typedef enum approach:

```
typedef enum
{
   limit   = -2,
   timeout = -1,
   ongoing =  0,
   finished=  1
} eTest;
```

Then the function would be defined as:

```
static eTest test(void);
```

What would you consider better of these two?
Or is there an better way to do this that I haven't thought of?

Comment: Both are ok, it depends on the use case, so this is **primarily opinion based**.

Comment: @Cool Guy: I have changed the comma. A name is not necessary, is it?

Comment: @iharob: Can you think of use cases examples for both versions?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with `enum`s but I think it is necessary.

Comment: @Cool Guy: I have tested it and it compiles; didn't execute it yet...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What would you consider better of these two?

In fact second version makes more sense to reader.

In first version, reader can't know what that `int` would mean, but second version give clue to reader about the return value.